# $resource and $q to set dropdown init value

Tags: angularjs, resources, q

I have a data service that says:

```
myApp.factory('locationsData', function ($resource) {


return $resource('/api/Location/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });});
```

I then use these locations to populate a dropdown in my view:

```
<select ng-model="locationId" ng-options="item.LocationId as item.LocationName for item  in locations"></select>
```

I want to set the init value of the dropdown in my controller with:

```
$scope.locationId = 8;
```

This doesn't work, i think because of the async nature of $resource -- it doesn't have the list yet so i can't set it.

I know $q is designed to address this, but not sure on how to create the promise, and set

```
$scope.locationId = 8;
```

after it is fulfilled

I've read the $q and $resource documentation, but i have yet to see a good code sample of how one would do a simple get like i'm doing, and then execute some function/action after the get promise is fulfilled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe somewhere in the controller you would be doing

```
$scope.locations=locationsData.query();
```

The query or get method can take argument for success and error functions. Something like

```
locationsData.query(function(data){
});
```

So you should set

```
$scope.locationId = 8;
```

inside the success function of the query.

Comment: So i don't need $q ? This seems to work. Except when the ng-model property is on an object e.g. `$scope.location.locationId`, when i try to access it in the controller, e.g. `$scope.location.locationId = 8;` it doesn't go. I can fix that by doing `$scope.location = [];` in the controller, but then when i submit my form, the location object is empty. I'm probably doing something stupid here.

Comment: You don't. Also $scope.location.locationId would work as long as your binding in html template is ng-model="location.locationId".